# LaTeXiT does not render anymore

Tags: latexit

I have a weird problem with LaTeXiT 2.8.0 on MAC 10.11.5

It isn't rendering anymore. Even a simple \alpha isn't shown although there is no error message. I tried all different modes like Align, Display, Inline, Text and even Auto.

[image: Rendering doesn't work]

Drag and drop my old formulas from the built-in bibliography will work, formulas are rendered correctly, but pressing "LaTeX it!" button will dismiss the content without any error messages.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Did you recently update to El Capitan?

Comment: No, I didn't update to El Capitan but I did an update using the TeX Live Utility.

Answer (score 28):

After flailing around with this problem, I have discovered that you must first follow the instructions referenced on the "Upgrading for El Capitan" page: upgrade LaTeXit to 2.7.5, and then open the "Preferences/Typesetting" pane and clicking the "Reset..." button. This finds the locations for the installed pdflatex and Ghostscript.

However, there is one more step needed. The default Ghostscript call is listed as:

`/usr/local/bin/gs-noX11`

if you replace this with:

`/usr/local/bin/gs`

the problem is solved.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! On my recent installation of TeX Live 2016, `/usr/local/bin/gs` is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/bin/gs-X11`. I don't know whether the installer looks whether XQuartz is installed on the machine and decides consequently.

Comment: Thanks for your kind welcome. I'd still appreciate an answer to the question I asked below, that you deleted. I am not trying to be negative, I really am asking for my future edification.

Comment: Oddly, on my install, `/usr/local/bin/gs` is a simlink to `usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.19/bin/gs`. Apparently, homebrew replaced the default simlink with its own. Or something.

Comment: This is not a forum; the space below questions is reserved for answers. Please ask a new question and link to this one.

Comment: About `gs`: I installed TeX Live 2016 a few days ago, so apparently it overrode Homebrew's ghostscript.

Comment: "Please ask a new question and link to this one."

OK. That seems suboptimal, but if that's how it works, fine.

Comment: @Glen: Thanks for response. Replacing the path for Ghostscript call to `usr/local/bin/gs` solved the problem

Comment: @egreg: MacTeX is broken into three parts. One installs The full TeX Live along with some data structures, etc., together the PATH correct and allow for easy switching of active distribution. A second part installs a set of GUI apps and some documentation. The final part installs Ghostscript. By default all parts are installed but you can do a custom install and uncheck the Ghostscript install for just such a situation.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer---I stopped using this app for years because I couldn't solve this problem, but your fix did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Am using El (Horrible) Capitan and I had the same problem. The only thing that solved my problem was:

```
$ brew link --overwrite ghostscript
```

How I found it?
I opened the terminal typed:

```
$ gs
```

The output was

> GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Can't find initialization file gs_init.ps.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Some helpful informatione:[How do I write a good answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Meet the same problem on Mac Catalina 10.15.6. This helped me! After running the `brew link ` command, the symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/gs -> /usr/local/bin/gs-noX11` changes to `/usr/local/bin/gs -> ../Cellar/ghostscript/9.53.3/bin/gs`. And after following Glen's instructions, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to http://www.tug.org/mactex/sierra.html and read the information there as well as the `Updating for El Capitan' document linked there.

Note: the original link (http://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html) was broken.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed the instructions 'MacTeX-2015 and El Capitan' and found that everything was already set to the right path. So there is still the same problem... no rendering, no error messages.

Comment: Finally changing the Ghostscript path to `usr/local/bin/gs` solved the problem.

Comment: If you had xQuartz when you installed MacTeX make sure it's updated to the latest version under El Capitan.

Comment: @HerbSchulz == authoritative source.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue but on Apple Silicon (M1 Pro, to help search engines...). The problem was that LatexIt was looking in `/usr/local/bin`, but `brew` installs everything in `/opt/homebrew/bin/` on Apple Silicon.

I had to open LatexIt, and in the prompts for `ghostscript`, `ps2pdf`, and `dvipdf` point it to `/opt/homebrew/bin/gs`, `/opt/homebrew/bin/ps2pdf`, and `/opt/homebrew/bin/dvipdf` respectively.

Generally, you can find `gs`/etc. by typing this in your terminal:

```bash
which gs
```

I had the [brew](https://brew.sh)-installed [mactex](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/mactex) bundle version 2021.0328, on macOS Monterey 12.3.1.

Comment: This is actually the most current answer for people using homebrew. Thank you!